# Swift: UIButton empty in storyboard but has text while running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uibutton

I'm developing a radio button module and I want an invisible button in a view.

I have deleted the text in the storyboard but when I run it, it shows "Button."

Here are some images:

### **Working version in the storyboard:**

[image: working version]

### **Wrong version in runtime:**

[image: not working version]

### Here's what I've tried:

- enabling the "ishidden" property
- making it transparent
- setting titleLabel.text to nothing (surprisingly the text comes back after clicking)

Setting the titleLabel.text = "" works until it is clicked where then the text returns.

Comment: can you show your code? not sure why you are setting titleLABEL if its a button thats doing it, you should be able to set `button.setTitle("my text here", for: .normal)` and if needed... `button.setTitle("my text here", for: .selected)`

Comment: Bloody legend it worked. I didn't really know what I was doing with the titleLabel... my bad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you have to use type `system` for button in storyboard with style `default`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced this issue after I update my Xcode. Till then all buttons with empty title were showing fine. But after the update it started to show "Button" text for every empty buttons on device. At the same time in storyboard it was empty.

Writing `button.setTitle("", for: .normal)`
everywhere was a difficult task since there were many buttons.

So after spending hours I discovered how to fix it.

1. Go to storyboard
2. Select the button
3. Go to attribute inspector
4. Select the style to default if it is something else (Mine was "Plain")
5. now it might be showing title as "Button". Remove it.
6. Thats it! now it won't show the text.

[image]

Comment: It woked for me, Xcode 15,  thanks!