# Some objects in storyboard are not using specified configurations like font

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm a beginner with Swift and Xcode. On my Views, I'm specifying objects like buttons and labels to have a specific font. They look good, but when I run the target and the iphone emulator launches, some of the buttons and labels revert to the default font. Why is this? I've done the same thing for all labels and buttons, and some of them display the font I want, and some don't. I've tried unsetting and resetting the font but it isn't working.

Here it is in xcode
[image]

And here it is in the iphone simulation
[image]

This problem is happening with around 40 different objects throughout different views.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: UIButton empty in storyboard but has text while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458504/swift-uibutton-empty-in-storyboard-but-has-text-while-running)